# Application logic inside a Spring entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

```
@Entity
public SampleEntity {

  @Id
  private long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;

  public SampleEntity(String name) {
     // some logic
     description = doSomeThing(name);
  }

  public SampleEntity() {}

  // getters and setters
}
```

Say I want to update description when only the `name` is being passed.

If I send POST request as follows:

```
/POST books
{
    "name": "some_name"
}
```

`description` property in the response will still be `null`.

I'm using [spring-data-rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) with `spring-data-jpa` to expose my Entities without defining any custom controllers. If I have to separate the  logic outside of my Entity class, please give me a simple example that could achieve that that with spring-data-rest.

Comment: Why do you have a description in your entity if it's directly derived from the name? The description is redundant. Just remove it from the entity. Otherwise, you also need to 1. remove the setter of description, make the setter of name also derive and set the description.

Comment: description is derived from name if the description is not explicitly passed.

Comment: The thing is, the JSON marshaller doesn't call your constructor taking a name as argument. It calls the no-arg constructor, and then sets the various properties. This logic shouldn't be in the entity. It should be in your service.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I can't seem to find out a tutorial that implement a service layer with spring-data-rest though.

Comment: As far as I understand, the idea of spring-data-rest is to basically expose your database and repositories as REST endpoints, and not to build actual services with real logic. I'd personally never use that stuff.

Comment: @JBNizet One should not use spring-data-rest unless you know what you're doing. MVC approach seems much simpler. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to put logic inside Entity class. What you need in this case is Annotated Handler `RepositoryEventHandler` . There are various annotations `@HandleBeforeSave` which would facilitate what you are looking for.
Here is an example [here](https://jaxenter.com/rest-api-spring-java-8-112289.html)